# Why isn't go build finding Py_None?

Tags: python, python-3.x, go, cgo

I'm wrapping a Go library for Python. I need to be able to return None, but it's not finding it at compile time:

```
/*
#cgo pkg-config: python3
#define Py_LIMITED_API
#include <Python.h>
*/
import "C"

//export Nothing
func Nothing(self, args *C.PyObject) (status *C.PyObject) {
    C.Py_IncRef(C.Py_None)
    return C.Py_None
}
```

Here's the output of `go build`

```
go build -buildmode=c-shared -o mymodule.so
# example.com/mywrapper
/tmp/go-build293667616/example.com/mywrapper/_obj/_cgo_main.o:(.data.rel+0x0): undefined reference to `Py_None'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm not understanding how it can be finding all of the other Py* functions and types (`PyArgs_ParseTuple` and `PyLong_FromLong` work just fine), but can't find `Py_None`. The Python library is obviously being loaded. What's going on here?

Comment: Looks like `Py_None` is a macro: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/321fd597f9dff757185bcfeb5fc39536746e06ab/Include/object.h#L908

Comment: Wow, I never would have guessed that. How on earth are you supposed to return None from Go? Surely this is something that somebody's bumped into...

Comment: I don't know anything about cgo, but presumably you can somehow refer to the address of `_Py_NoneStruct`, which is what `Py_None` expands to.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to a comment from [Ismail Badawi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/281108/ismail-badawi), the answer is to write a function in C that returns None. This is required because `Py_None` is a macro, which Go can't see.

**none.c**

```
#define Py_LIMITED_API
#include <Python.h>

PyObject *IncrNone() {
        Py_RETURN_NONE;
}
```

**mymodule.go**

```
/*
#cgo pkg-config: python3
#define Py_LIMITED_API
#include <Python.h>

PyObject *IncrNone();
*/
import "C"

//export Nothing
func Nothing(self, args *C.PyObject) (status *C.PyObject) {
        return C.IncrNone()
}
```